# Java code gives no output, returns "java -classpath .:target/dependency/* Main"

Tags: java, function

I'm trying to create Java code that will find the area of the following sketch:
[I'm trying to find the area of this shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yNVa.jpg)

However, my code (after debugging) returns the following in the console:
`java -classpath .:target/dependency/* Main`

Here is the code that I tried to run:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    areaObject(10, 12, 8, 6);
  }
  
  static double areaObject(double rectangleLength, double rectangleWidth, double triangleHeight, double missingTriangleHeight){
    double rectangleArea = rectangleLength * rectangleWidth;
    double triangleArea = 0.5* triangleHeight * rectangleWidth;
    double missingTriangleArea = 0.5 * rectangleWidth * missingTriangleHeight;
    return rectangleArea + triangleArea - missingTriangleArea;
  }
}
```

I just started learning Java and decided to try and go back to the basics, and tried to add two numbers with functions. However, the code returned the same response;

`java -classpath .:target/dependency/* Main`

Here is the code for adding two numbers:

```
class Main{
  public static double addition(double firstNum, double secondNum){
    return firstNum + secondNum;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    addition(2, 3);
  }
}
```

I'm sorry if I'm slandering Java syntax or breaking lots of Java rules; I am new to Java and just started learning. Thank you!

Comment: Just to verify that you are using the tools correctly, you could try typing in and running a Hello World program; e.g. the one in [Lesson 1: The hello world application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html).  If you can get it to say "Hello World" you are compiling and running it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The console is displaying the command used to execute your program; your program does not currently *output* anything.

```
areaObject(10, 12, 8, 6);
```

Gets the area but does nothing with it. Presumably you want to display the result like

```
System.out.println(areaObject(10, 12, 8, 6));
```

Which outputs

```
132.0
```

The second program also outputs nothing.

```
System.out.println(addition(2, 3));
```

Would output

```
5.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely forgot that you still have to do System.out (I used to code in Python where you can just put the function name in and print the result)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

System.out.println(areaObject(10, 12, 8, 6));

and

System.out.println(addition(2, 3));

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When replying to a question, please check to see whether it has already been answered. If your answer doesn't differ significantly from the existing answers, then you can upvote the answer that matches your answer.